# Accessing location.host inside NgModule

Tags: angular, typescript, adal

I'm trying to use Angular Adal to authenticate my application's admin interface with Azure AD however I'm running into some issues with the `redirectUri`. I want to get the current app's host (`location.host`) and substitute that into the `redirectUri` parameter so that no matter where this app is running it substitutes the correct callback URL when calling AD

Ideally, my config in `admin.module.ts` would look something like this:

```
MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot({
  tenant: '[Removed]',
  clientId: '[Removed]',
  redirectUri: `https://${location.host}/admin`,
  endpoints: {
  },
  navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: `https://${location.host}/logout`,
})
```

This works fine in develop mode, however because of Angular's AOT the `location.host` is replaced with `null` once I do a prod build of this application. I have done some investigation and it was suggested to use an `InjectionToken` to substitute this value in at runtime. I now have something like this in the `admin.module.ts` file, prior to the `@NgModule` section :

```
const REDIRECT_URI = new InjectionToken<string>('REDIRECT_URI');

export function redirectUriFactory() {
  console.warn('redirect to', `https://${location.host}/admin`); //debug correct uri
  return `https://${location.host}/admin`
}
```

and then in my `NgModule` I'm doing

```
MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot({
  tenant: '[Removed]',
  clientId: '[Removed]',
  redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
  endpoints: {
  },
  navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: `https://${location.host}/logout`,
})
```

with my providers including the `REDIRECT_URI` as follows:

```
providers: [
...
  { provide: REDIRECT_URI, useFactory: redirectUriFactory }
]
```

However, this is causing an error when I try to authenticate as it is passing the RedirectUri as `InjectionToken REDIRECT_URI` rather than the value that I want as specified by my `redirectUriFactory` function.

How can I get the `location.host` inside my `admin.module.ts` file successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As correctly said, angular AOT compiler is replacing the variable with null as location.host is not available during compilation. One of the way to avoid this problem is to use JIT compiler instead of AOT compiler as during JIT compilation this variable should be be available. ([Choosing compiler](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#choosing-a-compiler))

Apart from it, I believe it would be difficult to pass hostname to redirect url. If this would have been function, you could have written function to do so but this is expecting property/variable and hence difficult to do.